# How to say "discomfort" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am trying to figure out how to express "discomfort" in German. It seems to me that there is no general noun, and every dictionary tells me something else. Here is a simple sentence:

> The discomfort of the chair is causing me physical discomfort.

I have come up with many, seemingly wrong, attempts to this translation:

- "Der Diskomfort des Stuhles bereitet mir Unbehagen."
- "Die Unbequemlichkeit des Stuhles bereitet mir körperliche Beschwerden."
- "Die Unbehaglichkeit des Stuhles bereitet mir Unwohlsein."

Can somebody help me from going crazy and lend some help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chairs are indeed either **bequem** or **unbequem**. The most simple way to say what you intend to say is:

> Dieser unbequeme Stuhl tut mir im Rücken weh.

In contrary anything with *Beschwerden* sounds terribly stilted.

> Dieser unbequeme Stuhl bereitet mir Beschwerden. (stilted)

*Die Unbequemlichkeit* is an euphemism for small but annoying shortcomings:

> Die Sitze im Flieger waren in Ordnung, die Unbequemlichkeit war es, aus der Sitzreihe hinaus zur Toilette zu kommen.

**Behaglich** in contrary means *cozy*, **unbehaglich** either *not cozy* or even *frightening*.

**Unwohlsein** is *sickness*. Either of your guts or your head, ot both. Not your skin, bones, muscles etc.

Comment: A bit less stilted than *bereitet* would be *verursacht*:

Comment: The sentence "The discomfort of the chair is causing me physical discomfort" sounds peculiar in English!  I would rewrite it as: "This chair is causing me physical discomfort."  (This way, he's not identifying the cause of his discomfort as discomfort but rather as the chair.)  Would it sound stilted to you to write the following?  "Dieser Stuhl bereitet mir Beschwerden."  Or: "Dieser Stuhl bereitet mir körperliche Beschwerden."

Comment: The stilted part in German is the *Beschwerden*. *Körperliche Beschwerden* is even more stilted, it's something your PR agent would say if they ask him why you left the stage in mid-play. (truth: had eaten too many tacos.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!  But now I'm confused about the proper use of _Beschwerden._  I get the impression that it's often used to refer to _complaints_ (e.g. „das Taco-Restaurant hatte zahlreiche Beschwerden über sanitäre Bedingungen“).  But it seems that _Beschwerden_ can also refer to discomfort.  For example, an article in _Die Welt_ states: „Die Furcht vor Gesundheitsrisiken durch elektromagnetische Wellen kann ohne objektiven Anlass bei bestimmten Menschen echte Beschwerden hervorrufen.“  Their fear causes them real discomfort.  Is that different from what the chair causes?

Comment: *Beschwerden* is a load put on you. *Beschweren* means putting weights onto something. All other meanings are derived from that.

Answer (score 5):

> The discomfort of the chair is causing me physical discomfort.

If you try to translate this sentence literally it may unavoidably sound a bit unnatural, but your second attempt is basically OK.

A sentence sounding more natural would be:

> Der Stuhl ist so unbequem, dass er mir körperliche Beschwerden verursacht.